# Wrap items to the next row, and keep space between and around equal

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I have a list of social icons, where 3 of them are on the first line and the other 2 should wrap to the next line, which they do. However the problem is that they displace, in the term of not being correctly 'spaced-between'. Is there a way to fix this in proper code? I know I could just make another row, and put them there, but that is not clean code I think.

(Btw, this is for small screens, so if you test it out, you need to shrink your screen size)

CSS:

```
#contactlist {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 list-style-type: none;
 justify-content: space-between;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
 width: 75%;
}

#contactlist img {
 display: block;
 height: 80px;
 margin: 10px auto;
 width: 80px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="contactlist"
 <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/maikvv/"><img src="assets/img/instagram.png"</a></li>
 <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/maikvv/"><img src="assets/img/instagram.png"</a></li>
 <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/maikvv/"><img src="assets/img/instagram.png"</a></li>
 <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/maikvv/"><img src="assets/img/instagram.png"</a></li>
 <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/maikvv/"><img src="assets/img/instagram.png"</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Not sure this is entirely what you're looking for, but if I understand correctly, your problem lies with the last two items and their horizontal position. Try: https://jsfiddle.net/7jqb5wb6/

Answer (score 0):

IMO, your flex properties are doing the correct thing. The output is how it should be. One thing that you can do is to remove the `justify-content` property and it will show the way you want. And give margin to the images so that there is space between them. More in code below..

```css
#contactlist {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*   justify-content: space-around; */
  padding: 0;
  background: red;
  width: 300px;
}
#contactlist li {
  /*   margin:  1px; */
  /*   background: yellow; */
  /*   align-items: flex-end; */
}
#contactlist img {
  display: block;
  height: 80px;
  /*   margin: 10px auto; */
  margin: 5px;
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="contactlist" <li>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/maikvv/">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/maikvv/">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/maikvv/">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/maikvv/">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/maikvv/">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes, though what I kind of meant was that the last two boxes space each-other out with equal space around them. So that the fifth box if below the third box.

Comment: @MaikelvanVeen, please clarify. I am not getting your point? :)

Comment: I fixed it! As you can see I made a mistake in the HTML, the image tags didn't have closing brackets. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need write your code in **old school**. Using `float: left;`. Flexbox have still issue in `safari` and `IE11`. Here is the old school code.

> In this code is 100% responsive with all browser and all devices.

I'm avoid to use `flexbox` in this situation.

```css
#contactlist {
  display: table;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
}
#contactlist li {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#contactlist li:not(:last-child){
  margin-right: 10px;
}
#contactlist li a{
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#contactlist img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: autuo;
  
}
```

```html
<ul id="contactlist"> <li>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/maikvv/">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/maikvv/">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/maikvv/">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/maikvv/">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/maikvv/">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Hope this help.